# $(ax+b)(bx+a)=10x^2+cx+10$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers. Find the two possible values of $c$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I know this seems simple but i am really struggling please help me thank you

Comment: Do you mean ?$$(ax+b)(bx+a)=10^2+cx+10 \\or\\ (ax+b)(bx+a)=x^2+cx+10 \\or\\(ax+b)(bx+a)=10x^2+cx+10 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(ax+b)(bx+a)=10^2+cx+10 \\or\\ (ax+b)(bx+a)=x^2+cx+10 \\or\\(ax+b)(bx+a)=10x^2+cx+10$$I  think 3rd is right 
$$so\\abx^2+(a^2+b^2)x+ab=10x^2+cx+10\\ab=10\\
ab=10 \to \begin{cases}a=1 & b = 10 \to c=a^2+b^2=1+100=101\\a=10 & b = 1 \to c=a^2+b^2=1+100=101 \\
a=2 & b=5 \to c=a^2+b^2=4+25=29\\
a=5 & b=2 \to c=a^2+b^2=4+25=29\end{cases}$$

Comment: yes the third is what i meant to ask sorry